# In AWS EMR, From Jupyter, pyspark's hive enabled spark session is only showing default database and not all hive databases

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

Have installed jupyter in AWS  EMR.
The following piece of code works fine in non AWS Env, but in AWS EMR jupyter is only showing default database in Hive.
From Hive shell, show databases I see 6 databases, but from jupyter it only shows default.
It shows 6 in non AWS cluster.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

 display(spark.sql('show databases').show())
```

---

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+

### None

spark

SparkSession - hive

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
v3.0.1
Master
local
AppName
Python Spark SQL Hive integration example

Answer (score 0):

```
settings = [
        ("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://xxxxx")  #from /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
        ] 
spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example").setAll(settings)
spark = SparkSession.builder. \
    config(conf = spark_conf). \
    enableHiveSupport(). \
    getOrCreate()
```